# An email confirmation with these payment instructions has been sent to

Tags: wordpress, paylater, donations

I am using CiviCRM 5.18.4 with WordPress 5.3.2.

On a Donation page, when "pay later" is available and selected, and when the option to send confirmation email is also selected, the "pay later" instructions that are displayed to the user include:
"An email confirmation with these payment instructions has been sent to ."

But no email address is displayed.  The email is sent OK, but the user is understandably worried.

I did see a question about this back in 2018, with a suggested code fix, but that fix has not been implemented.

If no one can fix the code, can someone suggest a workaround?  I do want to use the Pay Later option, without causing users to worry and me to look sloppy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like there's a fix just hasn't been confirmed yet:

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1255

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15314

If you can try out the patch and make a comment there that it fixes it for you it will help get it included faster.

Comment: Thanks for finding the patch.  Now if someone could just help this newbie implement this suggestion.  I have examined those pages, and followed links, but I admit I don't know (a) which bit of code I am supposed to grab, nor (b) where to paste it.

Comment: Ok yes if you're on 5.18 it might need to be a bit manual - if you look on the Files Changed tab at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15314/files there's some red and green changes listed to CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php. You want to delete the red lines from your file and add the green ones. The numbers on the left are line numbers but they don't exactly match up because of the version difference but they're close. The other file at the bottom is a test file which you won't have and can ignore. Make a copy of your ContributionBase.php file first just in case.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks very much for the clear instructions!

Comment: Thanks. Looks like will be in 5.23 now.